# How do I integrate lazyload & bxslider together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, jquery-lazyload, lazy-loading

I want to lazily load images in the [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides) (or any slider like control, which allows dynamic number of slides/images). I'm using lazyload for loading images lazily, but the images in the slider isn't loading lazily. All the images are getting loaded with the pages :|. Here is my code,

```
<link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {

    $(":not(#hcontainer) img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn"
      });

      $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        container: $("#hcontainer")
      });

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 1,
      maxSlides: 3,
      slideWidth: 170,
      slideMargin: 10,
      pager: true
    });

    });
      </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #hcontainer {
        height: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #inner_container {
          width: 900px;
        }
    </style>



    <div id="vcontainer">
      <div id="hcontainer">
        <div id="inner_container">
    <ul class="bxslider">
          <li><img class="lazy" src="1.jpg" data-original="1.jpg" alt="BMW M1 Hood"></li>   
    <li>      <img class="lazy" src="2.jpg" data-original="2.jpg" alt="BMW M1 Side"></li>
        <li>  <img class="lazy" src="3.jpg" data-original="3.jpg"  alt="Viper 1"></li>
        <li>  <img class="lazy" src="4.jpg" data-original="4.jpg" alt="Viper Corner"></li>
        <li>  <img class="lazy" src="5.jpg" data-original="5.jpg" alt="BMW M3 GT"></li>
        <li>  <img class="lazy" src="6.jpg" data-original="6.jpg" alt="Corvette Pitstop"></li>
    </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <img class="lazy img-responsive" data-original="2.jpg" width="465" height="574" alt="BMW M1 Side">
      <br/>
      <img class="lazy img-responsive" data-original="3.jpg" width="465" height="574" alt="Viper 1">
      <br/>
      <img class="lazy img-responsive" data-original="4.jpg" width="465" height="574" alt="Viper Corner">
      <br/>
      <img class="lazy img-responsive" data-original="5.jpg" width="465" height="574" alt="BMW M3 GT">
      <br/>
      <img class="lazy img-responsive" data-original="6.jpg" width="465" height="574" alt="Corvette Pitstop">
      <br/>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**p.s.** I'm open to use any other slider control, if it supports lazyloading.

Comment: You still have images that uses the src attribute. For the layloading to work, you need to remove all src attributes.

Comment: If I remove `src` then bxslider isn't loading images :|

Comment: can you make a js fiddle so we can play around with it?

Comment: I don't know, how to upload the bxslider and layload scripts :|. can you share a file host where I can upload these and add it to jsfiddle?

Comment: I created this jsfiddle for you. I made some modifications and i think it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/7uj1z19k/ basically i removed all the src attributes and the $(":not(#hcontainer) img.lazy") call along with the container attribute of the second lazyload call.

Comment: It doesn't work, as removing the `src` attribute screws the bxslider :|. You can check the fiddle

Comment: this post give tips on how to implement that https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/118
I would recommend using their jsfiddle (at the bottom of the page) and modifying it with your images

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest, that you try [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/). lazysizes automatically detects visibility changes, so you won't need to write any JS code to integrate it with a slider.

Everything you need to do is to replace `src` with `data-src`, add the class lazyload to your images and add the lazysizes script to your page.

```
<img data-src="image.jpg" class="lazyload" />
```

Here are some examples:

- [lazySizes with flickity](http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/ogPxEa)
- [lazysizes with flickity 2](http://codepen.io/aFarkas/embed/OVoavw/?theme-id=17133&default-tab=result&height=500)
- [lazysizes with flexslider](http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/OPzEzE)
- [lazysizes with isotope](http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/VYGvde/)

And in case you want to force to preload an image, simply add the class `lazypreload`.

Comment: Nice one! Can you help me with adding touch swipe events to it? I mean, I was using bxslider because it handles mobile touch events implicitly. Can we do same thing here?

Comment: lazySizes also works with bxSlider out of the box. These examples are just examples. So just use bxSlider with lazySizes and your done. Although I think flickity is currently one of the best sliders.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="lazy" src="http://www.llbean.com/images/spacer.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/450/200">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="lazy" src="http://www.llbean.com/images/spacer.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/500/200">
  </div>
</div>

$(function(){

    // create an options object to store your slider settings
    var slider_config = {
        mode: 'horizontal', // place all slider options here
        onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            var $lazy = $slideElement.find(".lazy")
            var $load = $lazy.attr("data-src");
            $lazy.attr("src",$load).removeClass("lazy");
        }
    }
    // init the slider with your options
    var slider = $('.slider').bxSlider(slider_config);
});
```